# webview highlighting not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview

After loading this code into webView:

```
 String fun = "javascript:function getTextPage(){" +

            "    if(document.caretRangeFromPoint){" +
            "       var caretRangeStart = document.caretRangeFromPoint(0, 0);\n" +
            "       var caretRangeEnd = document.caretRangeFromPoint(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);\n" +
            "    } else {\n" +
            "        return null;\n" +
            "    }" +
            "    var range = document.createRange();\n" +
            "    range.setStart(caretRangeStart.startContainer, caretRangeStart.startOffset);\n" +
            "    range.setEnd(caretRangeEnd.endContainer, caretRangeEnd.endOffset);\n" +
            "    alert(range.toString());" +
            "};";
    loadUrl(fun);
    loadUrl("javascript:getTextPage()");
```

method **findAll()** or **findAllAsync()** find text but doesn't highlisht it

Comment: try this    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: it's done already!